# Sending an object through ajax to rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested form

```
form_for @post do |f|
 f.fields_for @ingredients do |ingredient|
  ingredient.text_field :name
 end
end
link_to "Add ingredient","#"
```

This is the basic structure. I want a new name field added when you click on "Add ingredients". As I have to pass ingredient(form builder) for making a new field, I am unable to use ajax. There is no way for me to make a new ingredients object using java script in rails.

I see, people working with link_to_function. But I see that is deprecated.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Do you just want to send the text field value to controller action ?

Comment: i want to add a text field for adding ingredient name in the form.

Comment: If it's just a text field you can add that through Ajax using append()

Comment: what wud you giv inside append. input["name"] will be a an array. and it should keep on changing as I add more text_fields.

Comment: Like this $('.[class_name]').append("<input class = 'url' type='text' value=''>")

Comment: That's an ugly solution. I will have to change the "name" each time I add a field, otherwise all the added field would have same name. I just need to know a way to execute a rails method by clicking a link, without going to another controller or action.

Comment: Yes you can make it dynamic ,read the name using the id/class and use the same inside append using variable .